# Django form choices disappear on page refresh

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I have a Django form that has a select field to choose a User for a ForeignKey relationship. Initially when the page loads it displays the select field with all Users as options. When refreshing the page (or reloading as a result of validation errors) the select field has no options. Continuing to refresh loads them sometimes but not consistently.

forms.py:

```
user_choices = ((obj.id, obj.email) for obj in User.objects.all())

class EditContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['title', 'user']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditContentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['title'].widget = TextInput(attrs = {'class' : 'form-control'})
        self.fields['user'].widget = Select(attrs = {'class' : 'form-control'}, choices = user_choices)
```

I've used Django forms to do this many times and never seen this issue. Any ideas are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a generator for the choices, for some reason. After the first time, it'll be exhausted.

At the very least, you should move that definition inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: Is there an alternate method you would suggest?

Comment: No. What's wrong with my suggestion? Even if you made it something other than a generator, you would still have the problem that newly added users would not show up in the choices until you restarted your server, which is unlikely to be desirable. Move it inside the method, as I suggested.

Comment: Daniel that seems to have worked, thanks for the suggestion. I was asking if there was something other then a generator that I should be using.